# Compilation errors when attempting to use SFINAE (std::enable_if) and template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Consider the code:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct CByteArray {};
struct HLVariant {
    HLVariant() {}
    HLVariant(const HLVariant&) {}
    HLVariant(const CByteArray&) {}

    };

template <typename T>
inline CByteArray serialize(const typename std::enable_if<true, T>::type& value)
{
    return serialize(HLVariant(value));
}

template <typename T>
inline CByteArray serialize(const typename std::enable_if<false, T>::type& value)
{
    return CByteArray();
}

template <>
inline CByteArray serialize(const HLVariant& value)
{
    return CByteArray();
}

int main()
{
    serialize(0);
    serialize(CByteArray());
    serialize(HLVariant());

    return 0;
}
```

Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 gives the following error:

> C2912: explicit specialization 'CByteArray serialize(const HLVariant &)' is not a specialization of a function template
>
> error C2783: 'CByteArray serialize(const std::enable_if::type
>   &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'

The error suggests that there's no `template <typename T> CByteArray serialize(const T&);` function visible to the compiler, and I don't understand why. Note that I'm simply using `true` and `false` for `enable_if` condition for testing purposes here.

I've also tried this way instead (`enable_if` on return type instead of argument):

```
    template <typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<true, CByteArray>::type serialize(const T& value)
{
    return serialize(HLVariant(value));
}

template <typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<false, CByteArray>::type serialize(const T& value)
{
    return CByteArray();
}
```

Now the error is:

```
C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::enable_if<false,CByteArray>'
```

Comment: I think if you do it with structure spécialization it will work... (working on it)

Comment: For SFINAE, the condition should depend of a template parameter.

Comment: `template <> inline CByteArray serialize(const HLVariant& value)` Since you don't explicitly specify the template arguments, the compiler will have to deduce them (from the function parameter type). But that's no possible since for both `serialize` templates, `T` is in a non-deduced context.

Comment: `std::enable_if<false, CByteArray>::type` Since there is no type dependent on a template parameter, no substitution takes place here, therefore the error does not occur during substitution (=> hard error, no SFINAE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typename std::enable_if<true, T>::type` is not deductible in your context (which `T` should the compiler test, it may be an infinite type for the general case).

You may use instead:

```
template <typename T>
inline
typename std::enable_if</*your condition depending of T*/, CByteArray>::type
serialize(const T& value)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: `true`/`false` doesn't depend of `T`, so you have an hard error, and not a substitution failure.

Comment: I see! Almost there, but not quite yet. Now it compiles with ideone, but MSVC still gives an error `'type' : is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'std::enable_if<false,CByteArray>'`. See here for code: http://ideone.com/WTaWpD